# Read file with swift in iphone

Tags: iphone, swift, url

I need to read a file with swift in my iphone.
In my computer I use this code and function correctly. The file "test.txt" is in my Desktop.

```
import UIKit

class Controller: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let sourcePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myname/Desktop", isDirectory: true)
        let file : URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "test.txt", relativeTo: sourcePath)

        let filemgr = FileManager.default

        if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: file.path){
            do{
                //Code to Parse text
            } catch let error as NSError{
            print ("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to read this file in my iphone. But I don't know which is the URL to read the file. Where I can save the file and which is the URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is for this question is you can not read file from you desktop to your device. That file should be in your app document directory or you need to add that file into your project.

After that you can read it into device.

Comment: The problem is that I need that the user download the file (from e-mail, dropbox, drive..), because the file will be update every 2 or 3 weeks. Then I need that the program find the file or the user save a file in a determine rute to read with swift.

Answer (score 0):

1- Drag the text file to the project and select `copy Items If needed`

2- Use this to read it

```
do {

    if let path  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "txt") {

        let str = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: .utf8)

        print(str)
    }


}

catch  {

    print(error)
}
```